# Connect two computers (one monitor along with one cpu each) with one keyboard and mouse

Tags: cpu, monitor

I have two separate computers (two monitors and two cpu's) with Ubuntu 16.04   on both the computers. So, how can i connect these two computers with one keyboard and mouse..??

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that? Can't you just use one computer with 2 monitors and duplicate the screen?

Comment: No. I have running simulations and calculations. So i have two computers (two cpu's and two monitors). I need to use them with one keyboard and one mouse. Is this possible..?? How..??

Comment: Google "KVM switch".

Answer (score 0):

Logitech offers "easy switch" in their mx performance mice:
https://www.logitech.com/assets/54026/13/mx-anywhere-2-setup-guide.png

I believe they should have the same mechanism for their higher-tier keyboards, but I can't find anything via google except K811

To work with this you would need 4 receivers total (for two input devices, each computer having two receivers connected)

if you're looking for a software-only solution, I don't think there is any.

Answer (score 0):

[Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) will do what you want. There used to be a free version but now it's only available as paid software. It's configured by setting one computer up as a client, the other as a server, then configuring the physical layout of your monitors. This then allows a single keyboard and mouse to control the two separate PCs, which also includes clipboard sharing.